# In this F# code how is the firstElem getting a value?

Tags: f#

In the below F# code how the firstElem getting a value? I got the code from the below this [link](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fvsc-quicksort/).

```
let rec quicksort list =
    match list with
        | [] ->                            // If the list is empty
            []                            // return an empty list
        | firstElem::otherElements ->      // If the list is not empty     
            let smallerElements =         // extract the smaller ones    
        otherElements             
        |> List.filter (fun e -> e < firstElem) 
        |> quicksort              // and sort them
    let largerElements =          // extract the large ones
        otherElements 
        |> List.filter (fun e -> e >= firstElem)
        |> quicksort              // and sort them
    // Combine the 3 parts into a new list and return it
    List.concat [smallerElements; [firstElem]; largerElements]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text indentation somehow got messed up when copying the text. In the original code from the link the let bindings of `smallerElements` and `largerElements` are both further indented than the match `| firstElem::otherElements ->`. So the answer is that `firstElem` gets its value from the matching with the head of the parameter/variable `list`.

Edit: The term head refers to the Head and the Tail of a list. The Head is the first element, and the Tail is all of the rest of the elements. E.g.

```
let ns = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let h = ns.Head
let t = ns.Tail
```

will return

```
val ns : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
val h : int = 1
val t : int list = [2; 3; 4]
```

with the caveat that Head and Tail is not defined for an empty list.

The lines

```
match list with
| firstElem::otherElements ->
```

will match the Head of `list` with `firstElem` and the Tail with `otherElements`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm new to functional and f# programming. What is the "head of the parameter" you are talking about? Can you give me the documentation link for it?

Comment: I was not being very clear here. Sometimes you say that a list is a Head and a Tail. The Head is the first element, and the Tail is all of the rest of the elements. I will add a few lines to the answer.